# How to transition between scenes in sceneKit SCNView

Tags: swift, scenekit

Hey there's an error in this code that I tried to modify for SceneKit. Im trying to goo from a sprite kit scene to a SCNcene

Code Not Working Below:

```
    let scene = PlayController()
    let scnView = self.view as! SCNView
    scnView.scene = PlayController()
    scene.size = scnView.bounds.size
    scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
    let reveal = SKTransition.fadeWithDuration(0.45)
    scnView.presentScene(scene, transition: reveal)
```

Code Working but for SpriteKit Only Below:

```
        let scene = GameScene()
        let sKView = self.view! as! SKView
        sKView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
        scene.size = sKView.bounds.size
        scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
        let reveal = SKTransition.fadeWithDuration(0.45)
        sKView.presentScene(scene, transition: reveal)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to:

```
import SceneKit
import SpriteKit
```

before the auto completion recognises what you want. Now you can type `scnView.presentScene(...`

Comment: these are both at the top of my controllers/my code. already do you mean put it in the actual transition code i have above

Comment: No only the class where your SCNView is. If auto completion works everything is fine

Answer (score 0):

The "presentScene" API in SceneKit has some extra arguments missing in your code. You need to specify the incoming point of view and provide a completion handler (both can be nil).

```
- (void)presentScene:(SCNScene *)scene withTransition:(SKTransition *)transition incomingPointOfView:(nullable SCNNode *)pointOfView completionHandler:(nullable void (^)())completionHandler NS_AVAILABLE(10_11, 9_0);
```

Comment: can you write it out as if you were actually using this in your project or can you rewrite my code from the question please